# graph java, removing vertex

Tags: java, graph, vertex

imagine that i have vertex  A B C D E F, so vertex C D F are connected to vertex A, using edges, what is the way for me to code to remove Vertex A and all the vertex connected to vertex A(C D F)??

this is my code to remove an edge betweeen two vertex, but what i want to do is to remove all the vertex connected to the first vertex. is there any way i could do it?

```
   public boolean removeEdge(T src, T dst){
        if (!hasEdge(src, dst))
            return false;
        Vertex<T, N> source = head;
        while (source != null){
            if (source.vertexObject.compareTo(src) == 0){
                Edge <T, N> currentEdge = source.firstEdge;
                if (currentEdge.dest.vertexObject.compareTo(dst) == 0){
                    source.firstEdge = currentEdge.nextEdge;
                    currentEdge.nextEdge = null;
                }
                else {
                    Edge<T, N> prevEdge = currentEdge;
                    while (currentEdge != null){
                        if (currentEdge.dest.vertexObject.compareTo(dst) == 0){
                            prevEdge.nextEdge = currentEdge.nextEdge;
                            currentEdge.nextEdge = null;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                source.outdeg--;
                currentEdge.dest.indeg--;
                System.out.println("Edge from " + src + " to " + dst + " has been removed.");
                return true;
            }
            source = source.nextVertex;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

ive manage to create a removeVertex and removeFirst code, here it is

```
  public T removeFirstVertex(){
        if (size == 0) return null;
     else {
         Vertex<T,N> temp = head;
         head = head.nextVertex;
         size--;
        
         return temp.vertexInfo;
     }
        
    }
    
        public boolean removeVertex(T vertex){
            System.out.println("vertex index: " + getIndex(vertex));
          
            if(getIndex(vertex)==0) removeFirstVertex();
         
            else{
            Vertex<T,N> current = head;
         for(int i=0; i < getIndex(vertex)-1; i++){
             current = current.nextVertex;}
             
            Vertex<T,N> temp = current.nextVertex;
            current.nextVertex = temp.nextVertex;
            size--;
            }
         return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

so after finishing the removeVertex & removeFirst, i can finally answered my first question, so heres the code, but u need to have a hasEdge() code too so i include it here also:

this is the hasEdge() code that will return true if the vertex is connected(has edge) with the mentioned vertex

```
public boolean hasEdge(T source, T destination){ //to check is there an edge
        if(head==null) return false; //Graph is empty
        if(!hasVertex(source) || !hasVertex(destination)) //vertex is out of bound
            return false;
        Vertex<T,N> sourceVertex = head;
        while(sourceVertex != null){
            if(sourceVertex.vertexInfo.compareTo(source)==0){
                //Reached source vertex, look for destination
                Edge<T,N> currentEdge = sourceVertex.firstEdge;
                while((currentEdge != null)){
                    if(currentEdge.toVertex.vertexInfo.compareTo(destination)==0)
                        //destination vertex found
                        return true;
                    currentEdge = currentEdge.nextEdge;
                }
            }
            sourceVertex = sourceVertex.nextVertex;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and this is the code to delete all the vertex connected to the desired vertex
u need to remove the edge first so that it will not print the edge and then u can remove the vertex

```
public void BFS(T vertex){
            
            for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
                
                if(hasEdge(vertex,getVertex(i))){
                    System.out.println(getVertex(i));
                    removeEdge(vertex,getVertex(i));
                    removeVertex(getVertex(i));
                    
                }
                
                else System.out.println(vertex + " dont have any edges");
            }
        
        }
```

if u want the getVertex() code, please tell

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: im sorry but can u tell which part is unclear